# order by and group by together not working without join

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id, page, params, timespent
FROM pagetrack
WHERE sessionid = '5asss123f640'
GROUP BY page , params
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Here id is primary key .By running this query the result is in ascending order but I need in descending order

Comment: With group by you need to specify all non-aggregated columns there. What result do you expect?

Comment: I want id to be descending order because the timespent column of last id have highest value .and also it must group by page name

Comment: where exactly is the join you are talking about in the title?

Comment: @sukanyamohan if the id is unique and you want to keep it in the results, group by does not make sense. Please update the question and show an example of data and expected result.

Comment: A group by without aggregate functions is unlikely to be useful also id and timespent may be indeterminate. Are you simply looking for the row which contains the most recent id for a page and params?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub query , First sql get all result and then in that result order by will be work

**When you use group by then same data will be group so id will be not exact**

```
SELECT main.* FROM (
                    SELECT id, page, params, timespent
                    FROM pagetrack
                    WHERE sessionid = '5asss123f640'
                    GROUP BY page , params
                  ) main
ORDER BY main.id DESC
```